# Do Postgres Fks get indexed automatically?

Tags: postgresql

Do foreign keys (in this case business_id below) automatically get an index in my table below or do I need to create one explicitly ?

```
CREATE TABLE xxxxx.client_credentials (
    client_credentials_id uuid DEFAULT extensions.uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
    business_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES nearly_handsome.businesses(business_id),
    name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    client_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    secret character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    is_active boolean default true,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);


CREATE INDEX client_credentials_client_id_idx ON xxxxx.client_credentials(client_id text_ops);
CREATE INDEX client_credentials_secret_idx ON xxxxx.client_credentials(secret text_ops);
```

Comment: You need to create one explicitly.

Comment: [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):"If the referenced column(s) are changed frequently, it might be wise to add an index to the referencing column(s) so that referential actions associated with the foreign key constraint can be performed more efficiently."